# How to obtain the field norm of a document in Lucene 6?

Tags: java, lucene

I want to compute TF-IDF scores, which are normalized by field norm, for each term in a field COMBINED_FIELD of various documents that are found via Lucene. As you can see in the code below, I'm able to get the term frequency for each term in a field of a document, I can also get the document frequency, but I cannot find a way to get the norm of this field at query time. All approaches I have found so far rely on methods that only exist in older Lucene versions, but not for Lucene 6. The way to go might be the usage of [LeafReader](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/LeafReader.html#getNumericDocValues-java.lang.String), but I didn't find a way of getting an instance of it.

Do you have an idea how I could get the norm of the field COMBINED_FIELD for each document?

Or can I use termVector.size() as replacement for the field length? Does size() consider the number  of 
occurences of each term or is every term counted only once?

Thanks in advance!

```
IndexSearcher iSearcher = null;
ScoreDoc[] docs = null;
try {
   iSearcher = this.searchManager.acquire();
   IndexReader reader = iSearcher.getIndexReader();

   MultiFieldQueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(this.getSearchFields(), this.queryAnalyzer);

   parser.setDefaultOperator(QueryParser.Operator.OR);

   Query query = parser.parse(QueryParser.escape(searchString));            

   docs = iSearcher.search(query, maxSearchResultNumber).scoreDocs;     

   for(int i=0; i < docs.length; i++) {
      Terms termVector = reader.getTermVector(docs[i].doc, COMBINED_FIELD);

      TermsEnum itr = termVector.iterator();
      BytesRef term = null;
      PostingsEnum postings = null;

      while((term = itr.next()) != null){
         String termText = term.utf8ToString();
         postings = itr.postings(postings, PostingsEnum.FREQS);
         postings.nextDoc();

         int tf = postings.freq();
         int docFreq = reader.docFreq(new Term(COMBINED_FIELD, term));
         //HERE I WANT TO GET THE FIELD LENGTH OF THE CURRENT DOCUMENT
      }
   }
} catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e.printStackTrace();         
} finally {
   try {
      this.searchManager.release(iSearcher);
   } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

**Alternively, is there a way to get the TF-IDF or BM25 value for each term of a field directly from Lucene?**

Comment: so, you want to compute norm or get length?

Comment: Actually, I want to have the norm which Lucene normally calculates during indexing as far as I know. However, if it is not possible, I would use the length as a proxy and would use my own norm with 1/sqrt(length).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucene internally computes the norms during indexing in the method `org.apache.lucene.search.similarities.Similarity#computeNorm`, then encodes it and stores on the disk in the `.nvm` files. Later, during querying/scoring it has been decoded only.

I think, one possible way to do it programmatically in the Lucene is to extend Similarity class and somehow get this information during indexing and store somewhere. Doesn't sounds to me like a best way to go, but at least something.

On the other hand, `BM25Similarity` computes the length this way:

```
discountOverlaps ? state.getLength() - state.getNumOverlap() : state.getLength();
```

where `getLength()` is the number of terms in the field, which you could calculate by iterating in the `while` as you do in your example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply!

Hmm, that could be a way and I already thought about this, but I thought that I might have missed something. I mean, Lucene does not really have a stable API, they are constantly changing nearly everything, but I'm puzzled with the question why they should remove a functionality they had offered before.

Iterating over the terms and multiplying by their frequence would be plan z, but sure, it is a way to do that. However, I think that Lucene might store this value somewhere which I could also access.

Comment: they changing it a lot, yes :) Yes, as i said, Lucene stores the norms in the .nvm files on disk, so you could probably read it manually and decode, but that's not that much Lucene API way

Comment: That's true! I mean, I could also find the code in Lucene that reads the nvm files and do it again manually, but that would be really strange wouldn't?
I guess your second approach would be the better (easier, likely faster) way of getting this information. By the way, size() counts every token only once thus not returning the full length of this field.